# When Using Left Join, how do I present data differentiating between empty string-values and non-existing values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar

I need to create a table with columns from different tables on different database environments, matching them with a common key across those tables. Many of those values have legitimate reason to be empty, but on some environments they don't even exist, which is a problem I need to identify, maybe by inserting a custom string, e.g. "\\NULL///"...

I have a set of pre-production environments, where each environment have a lot config-parameters in a table, that I have fetched into a huge table.

I am now trying to write an SQL to present certain set of parameters in a 2D-table (environment vs parameter x-ref value table), to identify problematic values, the lack of some parameters altogether.

```
SELECT x0.envName,
       x1.param1,
       x2.param2,
       x3.param3
FROM ( ( (
            (SELECT envName
             FROM paramTable
             GROUP BY envName) x0
          LEFT JOIN
            ( SELECT envName,
                     parameterValue AS param1
             FROM paramTable
             WHERE parameterName='param1' ) x1 ON x1.envName = x0.envName )
        LEFT JOIN
          ( SELECT envName,
                   parameterValue AS param2
           FROM paramTable
           WHERE parameterName='param2' ) x2 ON x2.envName = x0.envName )
      LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT envName,
                 parameterValue AS param3
         FROM paramTable
         WHERE parameterName='param3' ) x3 ON x3.envName = x0.envName)
```

If my parameterTable looks like this:

```
+ paramTable
=================================================
envName         | paramName     | paramValue    |
-------------------------------------------------
env1            | param1        | abcdef        |
env1            | param2        | 123456        |
env1            | param3        | A73BB2        |
env2            | param1        | klmnop        |
env2            | param2        | 987654        |
env2            | param3        |               |
env3            | param2        | uvwxyz        |
```

Then, the resulted table from this query will not differentiate between empty string-values (e.g as param3 on env2) from non-existing values (e.g. param1 and param3 in env3):

```
+ ResultQueryResult
=================================================================
envName         | param1        | param2        | param3        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
env1            | abcdef        | 123456        | A73BB2        |
env2            | klmnop        | 987654        |               |
env3            |               | uvwxyz        |               |
```

I'd like to moddify the SQL in a way so that the result query will get me something like this:

```
+ PreferedQueryResult
=================================================================
envName         | param1        | param2        | param3        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
env1            | abcdef        | 123456        | A73BB2        |
env2            | klmnop        | 987654        |               |
env3            | <<<!NULL!>>>  | uvwxyz        | <<<!NULL!>>>  |
```

Comment: RDBMS? With Oracle for instance this might not be possible since Oracle does not make a difference between empty strings and null values (...)

Comment: Don't mess up your data with something like `"\\NULL///"`, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Have a constraint that rejects empty strings.

Comment: @vc74 of course, I updated post with tag, it's Microsoft SQL Server!

Comment: @jarlh I am not going to modify the compiled table, but I need to present this "2D"-table in the way specified in OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   DECLARE @paramTable TABLE (envName  varchar(15), parameterName varchar(15), parameterValue varchar(15) )
   INSERT INTO @paramTable (envName, parameterName, parameterValue)
   VALUES 
       ('env1','param1','abcdef') 
      ,('env1','param2','123456') 
      ,('env1','param3','A73BB2') 
      ,('env2','param1','klmnop') 
      ,('env2','param2','987654') 
      ,('env2','param3',''   )  
      ,('env3','param2','uvwxyz') 

   select x0.envName, ISNULL(x1.param1,'<<!NULL!>>') as param1, ISNULL(x2.param2,'<<!NULL!>>') as param2,ISNULL(x3.param3,'<<!NULL!>>') as param3
   from
   (
     (
       (
         (select envName from @paramTable group by envName) x0      
         left join
         (
           select envName, parameterValue as param1 from @paramTable where parameterName='param1'
         ) x1
         on x1.envName = x0.envName
       )

       left join
       (
         select envName, parameterValue as param2 from @paramTable where parameterName='param2'
       ) x2
       on x2.envName = x0.envName
     )

     left join (
       select envName, parameterValue as param3 from @paramTable where parameterName='param3'
     ) x3
     on x3.envName = x0.envName
   )
```

Result:

```
           envName         param1          param2          param3
    --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
    env1            abcdef          123456          A73BB2
    env2            klmnop          987654          
    env3            <<!NULL!>>      uvwxyz          <<!NULL!>>
```

Comment: I actually tried this method, but I didn't provide an alias (as-statement) for the columns in the select-row, and so it didn't work... However, adding an alias as you showd actually solved the issue! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use a special const like `<<<!NULL!>>>` and change :

```
select paramValue
```

by

```
select nvl(paramValue,'<<<!NULL!>>>')
```

OR add a boolean colums (for each param) :

replace

```
select paramValue
```

by

```
select
    case when paramValue is null
    then True
    else False
    end as isParamValueNull,
    paramValue
```

Comment: This seems like what I need, but it is not working. 

Please note, nvl() turned out to be an oracle-function, the MS SQL counterpart is isnull()

Answer (score 0):

Include a NOT NULL field from the inner table into the result. Then when this field is NULL, you know that the inner row does not exist (as opposed to its NULL-able fields being NULL).

When JOIN-ing on a primary key, which has to be NOT NULL, you can use one of the PK fields (which seems to be `envName`/`paramName` in your case). Otherwise, you can just "invent" your own non-NULL field, by JOIN-ing on a sub-query:

```
...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 inner_exists, <other fields> FROM inner ...) Q
    ON ...
```

Avoid using "magic" values, since you never know if they can actually be present in the real data. Or, if you go down that route, use something that is very unlikely to be present, like GUID.

Comment: The query-result is intended to be used for presentation to a human eye, and will not be further processed. Therefore, using a "magic value" will probably be a better choice than including some kind of flag or other kind of "indication of existance"-column for each parameter.

One more argument for a "magic value" and against these extra fields is that the result will be exported to an excel file and should be filter-friendly; being able to filter on both "Blanks" and "Nulls" in the same column will probably be more intuitive for a more non-technical reader.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to rewrite your query:

```
SELECT x0.envName,
       CASE WHEN x1.parameterName='param1' THEN x1.param1 ELSE '<<!NULL!>>' END AS param1,
       CASE WHEN x1.parameterName='param2' THEN x1.param1 ELSE '<<!NULL!>>' END AS param2,
       CASE WHEN x1.parameterName='param3' THEN x1.param1 ELSE '<<!NULL!>>' END AS param3
FROM (SELECT envName
      FROM paramTable
      GROUP BY envName) x0
        LEFT JOIN paramTable x1
            ON x1.envName = x0.envName
```